# How to clear Media Storage app data programmatically?

Tags: android

How to clear Media Storage app data programmatically?

Am developing webview based application ,using html file including mp3 and video files.My app having 1gp media content when am running the app in 4.0.3 OS,
I am getting an error as "unfortunately process android.process.media has stopped"by when used continuously.when i faced this error i needed to clear the data of media storage app for skip this error in each time.this error occurred in 4.0.3 OS. i never faced this 4.3 and above

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: You have to post what have you tried.

Comment: Tnx for reply..edited..plz check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear the system media storage data in android mobile programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30238459/how-to-clear-the-system-media-storage-data-in-android-mobile-programmatically)